# ExtJS and Toolbar with many buttons

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

I have GridPanel with toolbar on it with many buttons. 
All buttons can't stand in one row so extjs show arrow to view those.
If I click tool button which is initially hidden nothing happens. On monitor with higher resolution same button is visible and click works.

I didn't manage to find nothing on the topic (it is obviously a bug).

Does anyone know workaround?

Comment: Report it to Ext on their forums (as as bug perhaps?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be a bug, but if it is, it doesn't happen only by implementing what you described.

I put together [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CgEKE/) (which is similar the same as [the toolbar overflow example at sencha](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/toolbar/overflow.html) but the window has a smaller width in order to hide some buttons) and every button  works great for me.

Maybe you can copy the way of doing it from there. Or maybe you can post the relevant code.

Comment: @Proton I create Toolbar buttons separately and then assign them an event handler by using 'on' function. If I use handler property while creating button,like in the example You provided, it works fine. I use Ext.Button constructor for toolbar buttons. Thank you, I have a workaround.